# Find the area of the region enclosed by $y=5x$ and $y=8x^2$

Tags: calculus

Sketch the region enclosed by $y=5x$ and $y=8x^2$. Find the area of the region. I'm having a hard time trying to set up the integral.

Comment: For what values of $x$ do the lines intersect?

Comment: The lines intersect at x = 0 and x = 5/8

Comment: Exactly, so the area you require is the area under the line $y=5x$ minus the are under the line $y=8x^2$. In each case the limits are those intersection points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Determine the solutions $x_1$ and $x_2$ of the equation $5x=8x^2$ such that $x_1 <x_2$.
2. Show that $8x^2 \le 5x$ for $x \in [x_1,x_2]$.
3. Compute $\int_{x_1}^{x_2}(5x-8x^2) dx$

Answer (score 0):

[image: plot]

You have correctly found out the points of intersection. Those $2$ points form the limits of integration. Also from the plot, it is clear that $5x$ lies above $8x^2$ for the range of the integration.

You can see that a plot is a very crucial part of such questions.